# Angular Array Does Not Empty Cart

Tags: node.js, json, angular, typescript, observable

I'm developing  a shopping cart using a client side api(json Server)
I'm trying to empty my shopping cart using an array, no matter what I
try the cart still keeps the same items. Here is how the app should work. When user is ready to check out they navigate to checkout page and choose their method of payment, if is successful the items should be deleted, so I call the handleclearCart function which calls the clearCart service. Once it clears, I call the reloadCartItems which should then say Your cart is empty, but the items are still there.  I cant figure out why.  **I don't get any errors** I show the responses, which is still the cart items.

Everything else works as expected.  I can't figure out what the problem is or what I'm missing or doing wrong. I have been doing some critical thinking, I just want to empty the array. I was thinking maybe  another set of eyes can help me or point me in the right direction.  I would really appreciate.  I have been stuck on this for a while.

Here is a snippet of code

snippet from db.json

```
"cart": [
    {
      "product": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Grey Jumper",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing 
         and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
         standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown 
         printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
         specimen book.",
        "imageUrl":"http://localhost:4200/assets/greyofftheshoulder.png",
        "price": 99
      },
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "product": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Red Onepiece",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing 
         and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
         standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown 
         printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
         specimen book.",
        "imageUrl": "http://localhost:4200/assets/redonepiece-r.png",
        "price": 160
      },
      "id": 2
    }
  ],
```

model

```
import { Product } from './product';


export class CartItem {
    id: number;
    productId: number;
    productName: string;
    qty: number;
    price: number;
    size:string;
    imageUrl:string;

    constructor(id:number, size:string,  product:Product, qty= 1) {

        this.id = id;
        this.productId = product.id;
        this.price = product.price;
        this.size = size;
        this.productName = product.name;
        this.qty = qty;
        this.imageUrl = product.imageUrl;
                 
    }
  
}
```

cartItem component

```
    export class CartItemComponent implements OnInit {
    
      form: FormGroup; 
     
      @Input() cartItem: CartItem
    
      addProperty;
      Valuesize:string;
      //cart;
     // items: CartItem[] = []
      cartItems = [];
    
    
      cartUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/cart';
    
    
    
      constructor(private cartService: CartService,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
    
    
      ngOnInit() {
    
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
          sizeBy: ['', Validators.required]
    
      });
      }
    
    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
      get f() { return this.form.controls; }
    
     /* I can rmove an item from cart with no problem function being called with 
       a button click*/
    
      handleRemoveFromCart(){

        alert("hit remove from cart");       
     
      this.cartService.RemoveProductFromCart(this.cartItem.id)
       .subscribe(() =>
         console.log("Product with Id deleted", this.cartItem.id),
          (err) => console.log(err)
        );
      
        console.log("trying to remove from cart ProductItem", 
 this.cartItem.id);
       
      }

    
       handleReload(){
        this.cartService.buttonClick()
        
        
      }          
       
    
        /* not working for me either*/

        handleClearCart(){
          this.cartService.clearCart();
          alert("Back to calling function");
        }
    
    
        /*Doea not work will never find id, it is undefined*/

         handleEmptyCart(){
          alert("Hit remove from cart");
          this.cartService.emptyCart(this.cartItem.id).subscribe(() =>
          console.log("Trying to clear cart", this.cartItem.id),
          (err) => console.log(err)
          );
      
        
        }
    
       
    }
```

cartService

```
export class CartService {

  id: number;
  size="M";
  product: any;
 // public cartItems: any = [];

 cartItem: CartItem[] = [];
    
  cartUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/cart';
  

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    
 }

/*To do  mapping the obtained results out to cart items props pipe and mapp functions will be used. The observable returneded by cartUrl is the source is going to pipe through the map projection and get results of CartItem*/


   getCartItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
     return this.http.get<CartItem[]>(cartUrl).pipe(
      map((result: any[]) => {
        let cartItems: CartItem[] =[];
         

        for(let item of result) {
            //cartItems =Object.assign({},cartItems,{size:  cartItems});
         
            cartItems.push( new CartItem(item.id, item.size, item.product, item.imageUrl ));
            
       }
         
        return cartItems;
        
       })
     );

        
   }
 
       
  /* Works as expected*/
   RemoveProductFromCart(id:number):Observable<void>{
    
     alert("show deleted item");
     return this.http.delete<CartItem[]>(`${this.cartUrl}/${id}`)
     .pipe(catchError(_err => of (null))
      
     );
    }

    buttonClick() { 
      const currentUrl = this.router.url;
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() => {
          this.router.navigate([currentUrl]);
      });
  
        //alert("Should Reload");
    } 
  
    /*Tried to empty array */

    clearCart(){

      alert("Inside service");
      this.cartItem = [];
       alert("Whats in cart" + " " + this.cartItem)
       console.log("Whats in cart" + " " + this.cartItem)
      
       //return this.cartItem;

     }



     /* Dosent work*/
     emptyCart(id:number):Observable<void>{
      alert("show deleted item");
      return this.http.delete<CartItem[]>(`${this.cartUrl}/${id}`)
      .pipe(catchError(_err => of (null))
       
      );

     }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to empty your cartItems Array in component only which you can do it. In emptyCart API Response. I am assuming you are calling the handleEmptyCart method as you have not mentioned the HTML part.

```
handleEmptyCart(){
          alert("Hit remove from cart");
          this.cartService.emptyCart(this.cartItem.id).subscribe(() =>{
          console.log("Trying to clear cart", this.cartItem.id);
          this.cartItems = [];
},(err) => console.log(err)
          );}
```

Comment: Hello I'm getting same error as before.  Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'id') When I do it this way. Did you take a look at the cart service code.  Yes I am calling  the handleEmptyCart from checkout component

Comment: Hello I moved  the HandleEmptyCart  CartItem Component to the Cart Component .  I no longer get the error but cart doesn't clear.  You mention some about my HTML not being mentioned I am not call the function from HTML.  I wonder if this is the issue?

Comment: Can you please add your HTML code as well?  it will give more ideas.

Comment: That is not the issue either I tried it from HTML.

Comment: That is not the issue either I tried it from HTML Here is a snippet
  
    <div *ngIf="cartItems.length === 0"class="alert alert-info">Your Cart is Empty</div> 
    
    <div *ngIf="product">
      <div>{{product.name}}</div>
      <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="product.num" min="0"/>
    </div>
    
    <!--<ul *ngIf="cartItems.length >  0" class="list-group">-->
      <div  *ngFor="let item of cartItems; let i = index">
        <app-cart-item  [cartItem]="item"></app-cart-item>  
      </div>
      
    </div>